# Is it necessary that for external and static variables, the initializer must be a constant expression?

Tags: c

While reading "The C Programming Language" by Dennis M. Ritchie I came across this line:

> *For external and static variables, the initializer must be a constant expression.*

I am unable to understand what constant expression means here because the below code compiles without any error, isn't the statement: *static int a = n-1* , a non constant expression? Please point out what am I missing here. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
int n;
cin>>n;

static int a = n-1;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++, not C.

Comment: You are missing a manual that is in sync with the version of your compiler.

Comment: @Jim - corrected for you, "You are missing a manual that is in sync with your programming language"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's necessary in C, but not in C++. They are different languages.

[The code compiles as C++](http://ideone.com/ryhW1t),

[but not as C](http://ideone.com/CMEeHO).

---

```
void foo() { this line is here because of stupid restrictions of Stack Overflow }
```

Comment: Thanks got my mistake! But why does C++ allows it and C doesn't?

Comment: @rishabh Because Bjarne Stroustrup thinks differently from Dennis Ritchie, and the former thought that lifting the constexpr restriction would be a useful idea, so he designed his language like so.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is C++, not C.  A very different language.  The book's statement is true for C, but not for C++.

Answer (score 0):

file main.c contents

```
int main()
{
int n;

static int a = n-1;

return 0;
}
```

Output of g++ main.c

```
//Emptiness because it is valid C++
```

Output of gcc main.c

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6: error: initializer element is not constant
```